# LaTeX Book - Sections with Different Layouts (e.g. Tips)

Tags: templates, books

I am getting familiar with book writing in LaTeX now and I am trying to create macros *(editted)* for sections with different layouts, for example

- Tips
- Memories
- Funny facts

Every time I use one of the layouts, I need it to automatically incorporate a template for, say, a "Tip", with maybe a different title, and when I write a "funny fact", I need it to invoke another template.

How is this achievable in LaTeX? What commands/macros do I need to use?

Comment: You should take a look at the  `titlesec` package. It defines  two main commands: \ titleformat`  and `titlespacing` to cutomise the layout of chapters, sections, &c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looing for are macros, commands and environments. They are not called templates in the LaTeX world.

[image: matevaMacros]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newenvironment{tip}{{\par\large\centering TIP \par}}{\par}
\newenvironment{funny}[1]{{\bigbreak\noindent\color{blue!20!orange}\large Fun fact: #1  \par}\noindent\ignorespaces}{\par}
\newtcolorbox{memory}[1]{title=#1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tip}
    \blindtext
\end{tip}
\blindtext
\begin{memory}{The night I met her}
    \blindtext
\end{memory}
\begin{funny}{Wombats are cute}
    \blindtext
\end{funny}
\end{document}
```